# Is it possible to access MY_Controller Public Function in CodeIgniter via browser

Tags: codeigniter

I am learning CodeIgniter. I have defined a MY_Controller Class residing inside Application/Core Folder.

Inside this, there is a public function.

My question is, Can I directly access this function or any other public function defined in My_Controller via the browser url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it it Possible.

If the method is public you can simply call it using any controller that extends My_controller and does not override the method ( i.e does not have a method with the same name as that defined in the My_Controller class) 
like so :

This is how you can do it. Create a simple controller which will extend My_Controller :

**someController.php**

```
class someController extends MY_Controller{

}
```

now you can access it from url as such :

> yourdomain.com/someController/yourMyControllerMethodName

Answer (score 0):

You can call it from browser URL.

So that inside your controller you should define `index()` function. Because when it calls to your controller and if there is no any method calling with it, CodeIgniter automatically call `index()` function.

So

1. `www.myproject.com/contact` - this will call `index()` function of `contact` controller
2. `www.myproject.com/contact/branch` - this will call method inside `contact` controller